# getting offsetLeft of a text range

Tags: javascript, textrange

Can anyone tell me why this code is returning `undefined`.

I was hoping this would give the left coordinate of the user selected text.

```
function alertRangeObject(){
    var userSelection;

    if(window.getSelection)
    { 
    userSelection = window.getSelection();
    }
    else if (document.selection)
    {
    userSelection = document.selection.createRange();
    }

    var selectedText = userSelection;
    if (userSelection.text)
    {
        selectedText = userSelection.text;
    }

    var rangeObject = getRangeObject(userSelection);

    function getRangeObject(selectionObject)
    {
        if (selectionObject.getRangeAt)
        return selectionObject.getRangeAt(0);
        else { //safari
            var range = document.createRange();
            range.setStart(selectionObject.anchorNode, selectionObject.anchorOffset);
            range.setEnd(SelectionObject.focusNode, selectionObject.focusOffset);
            return range;
              }
        }


       alert(rangeObject.offsetLeft);
   }
```

The frustrating thing is when you `alert(rangeObject)` I get the selected text. But I was I thought that if this was a text range I could use the `offsetLeft` method to get the left coordinates. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong.
Thanks.

Comment: You can use [this API](http://code.google.com/p/rangy/) to get all kind of information about the selected range.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`TextRange` objects do indeed have `offsetLeft` and `offsetTop` properties, but the code you've posted will throw an error in IE < 9 because the `getRangeObject()` function returns `undefined`. I'd suggest alternative code. The following will get you the top left coordinates of the selection relative to the viewport in IE >= 4 and recent versions of other browsers that support the [`getBoundingClientRect()` method of Range](http://www.w3.org/TR/cssom-view/#extensions-to-the-range-interface), and returns (0, 0) in other browsers.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NkSmn/

Code:

```
function getSelectionTopLeft() {
    var x = 0, y = 0;
    // Use standards-based method only if Range has getBoundingClientRect
    if (window.getSelection && document.createRange
    && typeof document.createRange().getBoundingClientRect != "undefined") {
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        if (sel.rangeCount > 0) {
            var rect = sel.getRangeAt(0).getBoundingClientRect();
            x = rect.left;
            y = rect.top;
        }
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
        // All versions of IE
        var textRange = document.selection.createRange();
        x = textRange.boundingLeft;
        y = textRange.boundingTop;
    }
    return { x: x, y: y };
}
```

I'm working on a Range/Selection position module for [Rangy](http://code.google.com/p/rangy) at the moment that uses a similar approach to the above. It's a work in progress but works pretty well in most scenarios and browsers. It should make it into version 1.3. Demo here: http://rangy.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/position.html

As an aside, that code looks like it's based on code from PPK's [introduction to Ranges page](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/range_intro.html) on quirksmode. It's out of date and the code is confusing and not ideal, but there should be some improvement there in the near future.

Comment: Thanks Tim, I was indeed using the "intro to ranges page". Thanks for the heads up. I'm going to spend a while getting familiar with Rangy. Also, thanks for the code above.

Comment: Blink and Webkit never surprise me. When range is collapsed they return rect `0, 0, 0, 0` when testing in contentEditable element. Something always must be wrong with these two engines ;>